# A misunderstanding in the uniqueness of $q,r$ in $a=bq+r$?

Tags: number-theory

I've seen a proof of the uniqueness of $q,r$ in $a=bq+r$ when $a,b$ are given. The proof is as follows:

> Suppose $a=bq+r=bq'+r'$ with the obvious assumptions on $q,r$, then:
>
> $$|r'-r|<b \quad \quad b(q-q')=r'-r$$
>
> If $q\neq q'$, then $|q-q'|\geq 1$, such that:
>
> $$|b|\leq |b||q-q'|=|r'-r|<|b|\tag{$\star$}$$
>
> A contradiction, and hence $q=q'$ and $r=r'$.

I've explored this proof in the following way: I assumed $|q-q'|=1$, and hence:

$$|b|\leq |b|=|b|<|b|$$

Picking any other value for $|q-q'|$ yield the same problem. Then I supposed $|q-q'|=0$ which is the consequence of the conclusion of the proof. And it gives me:

$$|b|\leq 0<|b|$$

Isn't this also a contradiction? I may have slipped some bad reasoning there, but I don't see where. I doesn't contradict the previous assumptions, but I guess somehow $(\star)$ can only be used when we suppose $|q-q'|\geq 1$.

Comment: If $q=q’$, then it isnt true that $|b|\leq |b||q-q’|$ (unless $b=0$)

Comment: @FedePoncio Yes, I also noticed that. But most of the times, $b$ won't be $0$.

Comment: $|q-q'|=0\iff q=q'$.  So that would mean $bq=bq'$ and $r=r'$. Anyway you *don't* get $|b|\le |b||q-q'|$ If $|q-q'|<1$.

Comment: "Then I supposed |q−q′|=0... And it gives me: |b|≤0<|b|".  That is simply dead wrong and completely nonsensical.  If $|q - q'| = 0$ then $1 > |q-q'|$. and  so $|b| > |b||q-q'| = 0$.  To get anything else is ... weird....

Answer (score 1):

You only have $|b|\leq |b||q-q'|$ because you assumed $q\neq q'\implies |q-q'|\ge 1.$  You can't change your mind and then assume $q=q'.$  If you assume $q\ne q'\wedge q= q'$ you can prove anything.

Comment: But I assumed $q\neq q'$, then I got that inequality. If I "start again" assuming $q=q'$, won't I reach the same inequality again? I'm a little bit confused with this, but I guess If I start assuming $q=q'$, then I already have the result I want to prove. It's like the inequality is a consequence of that assumption which couldn't be arrived at otherwise, but It's not clear why.

Comment: No you won't get the same inequality if you start again.  If $q\ne q'$ then $|q-q'|\ge 1$ because $q,q'$ are integers, and two distinct integers differ by at least $1$.  If q=q' then $|q-q'|=0$

Comment: If $q\ne q'$ then $|q - q'| \ne 0$.  $|q-q'| = 0 \iff q=q'$.  And $|b| \le |b|*|q-q'| \iff 1 \le |q-q'|$.  So if $|q-q'| = 0$ then $|b| \not \le |b||q-q'| = 0$ because $1 \not \le |q-q'|$.  There is no possible contradiction to be had.

Comment: And for $q,q' \in \mathbb Z$ then $|q-q'| \ge 1 \iff q\ne q' \iff |q-q'| \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $|q-q'|<1$ then $|b|>|b||q-q'|$

So you get $|b|>|b||q-q'|=0=|r-r'|<|b|$ which is not in the least bit a contradiction.

Instead if $|q-q'|= 0$ then $q=q'$ and $|r-r'|=0$ and so $r=r'$.

Comment: If you assume $q=q'$ and $r=r'$, don't you get:

$$|b|\leq |b|0=0<|b|$$

$$|b|\leq 0=0<|b|$$

$$|b|\leq 0<|b|$$

on $(\star)$?

Comment: Um... No.  Why in the heck would you get that?    $|q - q'| < 1$ so $|b|= |b|*1 > |b|*|q-q'| = 0$.  Why on *EARTH* do you think $|b| \le |b||q-q'|$??? That can only possibly happen if $|q - q'| \ge 1$.  And as $|q-q'| = 0$ that most assuredly does *NOT* happen.  We can say with absolute *CERTAINTY* then $|b| > |b||q-q'|$ if $q=q'$ and that *ABSOLUTELY $|b| \not \le |g||q-q'|$.